# Outlier of a group

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Single word to describe a person who is not part of a specialized group and is therefore unlikely to understand the vocabulary/concepts of said group. Usually used when asking members of said group to explain a concept to them like they were a _________.

Comment: explain it to me like I am a ________.

Answer (score 5):

[Layman](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/layman), in sense 2 of the Oxford English.

Alternatively, and only very informally, "explain like I'm five" means "explain in simple terms" (where "five" here means "five years old").

Comment: +1 See also: *Layman's terms*.

Answer (score 1):

"Put it in layman's terms for me."

[**in layman's term**s](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in_layman's_terms) ODOL
phrase

> Phrased so as to be easily understood, without the use of technical or obscure terms.
>   ‘They will explain things in layman's terms and work with you to not only help you reach the top but understand how you got there as well.’

(*Layman* has already been suggested by Patrick Stevens.) See [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/layman's%20terms) "Layman: a person who does not belong to a particular profession or who is not expert in some field"; "Layman's terms: simple language that anyone can understand *The process was explained to us in layman's terms.*"

Answer (score 0):

**Novice**, according to  [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/novice) (2 meanings that might fit):

> a person who is beginning to learn a job or an activity and has little or no experience or skill in it
>
> a person who is not experienced in a job or situation

Attribution: (Definition of “novice” from the Cambridge Academic Content Dictionary © Cambridge University Press)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct fill-in-the blank solution, but nonetheless it captures the same essence:

> Please explain in plain English.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_English

Answer (score -1):

Is this American phrase acceptable?

As in:

> Please explain X like I am a four year old.

[image: Denzel Washington in the movie *Philadelphia*]

Comment: some truth to this phrase in the U.S.  Insert any age you want something dumbed down to. Easy on the down votes!  Will remove

Comment: In the same vein "fifth-grader" or any grade your choice.

Comment: Continuing up the scale (and depending on the crowd) " [...] like they were a Liberal Arts major."